# Creating new managed property, but not able to do the "mappings to crawled properties"

Tags: crawling, enterprise-search, managed-property

I want to make a list column as "Managed Property".
Steps am following is, 
Central Admin -> Search Service application -> New Managed Property
gave name for "Property Name".
Checked as "Text" as column property.

But am not getting the column name when i click on "Add Mapping"
Can any one guide me, how to achieve this.

Do I need to do a crawl, then only the column name will be displayed?

Answer (score 2):

You need have at least one list item with valid value in this column.

Then you need to run full crawl. After the crawl is complete you will be able to see it as *ows_yourcolumnname*

Comment: Yes, you will need to run a crawl before your new column appears as a crawled property that can then be mapped.